# Java threads synchronization using token and character printing

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized

Okay, I've been attempting to understands threads and thread synchronization lately. I've written a program that is supposed to output abc, in that order, over and over again with each character mapped to a thread. Problem is, it's not working and I'm not sure why. Here's my code:

```
package application2;

public class Application2 {

private static int turn = 0;
private static String[] names = new String[3];

private static class syncThreads extends Thread {

    private final char charToPrint;
    //private final int times;

    public syncThreads(char charToPrint) {
        this.charToPrint = charToPrint;
        //this.times = times;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        String myName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            if (myName.equals(names[turn])) {
                System.out.print(charToPrint);
            }
            turn++;
            if (turn == 3) {
                turn = 0;
            }
        }

        notifyAll();
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().wait(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }

}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    syncThreads t1 = new syncThreads('a');
    names[0] = t1.getName();
    syncThreads t2 = new syncThreads('b');
    names[1] = t2.getName();
    syncThreads t3 = new syncThreads('c');
    names[2] = t3.getName();

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();

    //Join method ensures proper synchronization
    try {
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Interrupt Exception.");
    }

}
}
```

As you can see, I'm attempting to use a synchronized run() function that uses a token value to tell which thread to print. When I run this I get very strange results like aaaaaabbbbcccc and abbabbaaaaccccbbccc, etc. Any idea why these threads aren't being synchronized? What am I missing here?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Not only are you synchronizing on the wrong thing (this, rather than a shared object, as illustrated in the question that Chris linked), you are also *unlocking* in the wait action.

Comment: And you're waiting outside a wait loop.

Comment: This rather defeats the idea of concurrent threads - that they work asynchronously. It's hard because you're trying to pound in a nail using a screwdriver.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, trying to have the individual threads running in order defeats the whole point of concurrency. Just put them in one thread if that's what you want. If, on the other hand, you want to ensure all three threads have run before letting them start again then that is fairly easy:

```
import java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException;
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;

public class Sync {
    private static final CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(3);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new CharPrinter('a')).start();
        new Thread(new CharPrinter('b')).start();
        new Thread(new CharPrinter('c')).start();
    }

    public static class CharPrinter implements Runnable {
        private char c;
        private int times = 10;

        public CharPrinter(char c) {
            this.c = c;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(times-- > 0) {
                System.out.print(c);
                try {
                    barrier.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {  }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will output something like "bac/cba/acb/bca/abc/cab/bca/abc/cab/bca" (slashes added for clarity). Note that you always get a, b and c output in each group of three characters, but the order is indeterminate - as it should be for concurrent threads.